# How does the Node.js (v8) Garbage Collector work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I've done some tests with my node.js application looking for memory leak that my code supposed to do. I run script that in my opinion should leak memory, but I am surprised by the result.

```
redisClient.on('message', initRequest);

function onSuccess(self, json){
    console.dir(json);
}

function initRequest(channel, message){

  var request = new RequestObject({
      redisMessage: message
  });
  
  request.on('success', onSuccess);

}
```

redisClient emits a couple of 'message' events per second. This mean that `initRequest` function is called quite often. Each time `request` object is created in memory, and function `onSuccess` is bind to its 'success' event.

I assumed (but here I may be wrong), that as far as there is listener (`onSuccess` in this case) bind to this object it cannot be garbage collected. Then I thought, memory usage will grow since memory won't be free-ed up.

As a solution for this potential leak I wanted to use `.once` instead of `.on`, as this will unbind listener and object could be garbage collected.

I've used **pmap** to test both scenarios (comparing `.on` and `.once` and one another scenario that is not worth to mention here), and I haven't found a big difference.

[image]

To sum up I have 2 questions:

1. Is this normal GC behavior to clean memory in some intervals, or after it reach some threshold instead of continuous cleaning?
2. Am I correctly assume that example code with `.on` should leak memory, which I don't see on memory consumption graph?

Comment: Some thoughts... For the first question, yes it is normal. Garbage collection runs in cycles. When you no longer have references to some memory, it can be garbage collected, but there is no indication when that will happen. As for the second question, i would expect a memory leak there as well. Curios to see an answer why it is not visible in the chart.

Comment: For clarity, could you show the code with .once? I'm assuming you did it on the redisClient, but it's just guessing at the moment. Also, I do see a little higher usage in 1. The red line.. is that the 'leak'? A legenda would be nice. Since onSuccess is shared between all the initRequests, extremely little extra memory will be used, so if your requests all finish before they reach a few million, I wouldn't expect a much higher peak.

Comment: Which redis client module did you use? I searched for `RequestObject` and got nothing interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: yes :-)

2: In general the leaking of memory when using event listeners is that the object that is listening is prevented from being garbage collected because the object that is emitting is keeping a reference to it.

So in your code the `onSuccess` function will be referenced by your `request` object. However,  that `onSuccess` is only one function that is being reused as a listener for all request objects so that should not lead to memory buildup.

Sidenote: I don't know the innards of `redisClient` and `RequestObject` but to me it also looks like the `request` will be ready for garbage collection as soon as the `initRequest` function completes, that is possibly before any of its listeners are called.

Comment: It seems that my concers came from wrong assumptions regarding who is referencing who. Now I understand that event emmiter is referencing listener and not in opposit way.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i can see the request object should only exists within the initRequest function, and should therefor be marked for garbage collection when the function terminates.